# splitting URL regex after 4th slash

Tags: java, regex, powershell

I'm trying to split a URL into chunks. What I want is everything up until the 5th `/` .

I've tried looking around but I'm new to regex and I'm getting overwhelmed a bit.

url example is:

`http://daniel.mirimar.net.nz/Sites/reginald/DDD/CD`

So what I'd like from here is:
`http://daniel.mirimar.net.nz/Sites/reginald/`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Short and concise is always nice

```
(?:.+?/){4}
```

- `(?:` -- open non-capturing group
- `.+?/` -- lazily match anything till `/`
- `)` --  close non-capturing group
- `{4}` -- repeat four times

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex like this:

```
^.*?\/\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*\/[^\/]*
```

or

```
^.*?\/(\/[^\/]*){3}
```

And for checking without CRLF and URL with fewer parts:

```
^.*?\/(\/[^\/\n\r]*){1,3}
```

You can be more specific by this:

```
^https?:\/(\/[^\/\n\r]*){1,3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes `regex` can be a little overwhelming, especially if you're not familiar with it.  It even can make code more difficult to read ([Disadvantages of using Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505409/disadvantages-of-using-regular-expressions)).  Now, don't get me wrong, I like to use `regex` when the task is simple enough for it.  IMO, you're better off solving this without `regex`.  You can design a method to find the index location of the 5th "/" and then just return the substring.

Something like:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String url = "http://daniel.mirimar.net.nz/Sites/reginald/DDD/CD";
    System.out.println(substringNthOccurrence(url, '/', 5));
}

public static String substringNthOccurrence(String string, char c, int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return "";
    }

    int index = 0;
    while (n-- > 0 && index != -1) {
        index = string.indexOf(c, index + 1);   
    }
    return index > -1 ? string.substring(0, index + 1) : "";
}
```

Results:

```
http://daniel.mirimar.net.nz/Sites/reginald/
```